# How to sync checkbox inside toggle button in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, button, checkbox

I have a checkbox inside button:

```
<button ng-mousedown="active = !active">
    <input type="checkbox" ng-checked="active"/>
    Toggle!
</button>
```

Clicking the button toggles state variable `"active"`. I want to sync the checkbox with `"active"`. If I declare

```
ng-model="active",
```

the box is in sync with the button as long as the button is pressed outside the checkbox.

The problem is when the checkbox is clicked, it changes the state but also sends click event to the button, so both events fire and as a result, the box becomes out of sync:

http://jsbin.com/wepul/7/edit

The sync behaviour is restored when using `ng-click` instead of `ng-mousedown`, however, I prefer to use the latter as this way it feels more responsive (the button reacts faster).

Is there any (Angular) way I can keep the box in sync and keep the `ng-mousedown`?

Comment: `input` is invalid child of `button`

Comment: and keeping checkbox disabled is not an option, right ?

Comment: @charlietfl In what sense invalid? It works fine.

Comment: @coder disabling would make it look disabled, which is would be confusing, the checkbox should be functional

Comment: I would use `label` instead of `button` and you wouldn't need the `ng-mousedown` since label will always change `checkbox`

Comment: @charlietfl Could you give an example? Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you use the default behavior of `<label>` around a checkbox instead of `<button>` you can simplify any need for extra event handling. When a label is clicked it will automatically change any radio or checkbox within it

```
  <label ng-class="{active: active1}" >
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="active1"/>
    Change ng-checked!
  </label>
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/locevonulipi/1/edit)**</kbd>

Comment: +1 Thanks, works great too and looks DRYer! Good to know labels catch the events. And I can always wrap them inside a button :)

Comment: the other approach has too many event handlers, this is safer way to do it

Comment: Tried to put a `button` inside the `label` and it doesn't work anymore :( http://jsbin.com/locevonulipi/2/edit

Comment: not sure why you are fixed on a button, can style the label to match whatever button css you have. I have never ever seen an input in a button, makes no sense

Comment: True, I can restyle it as button. I am using in for my startup http://33hotels.com, now changed checkboxes to icons.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
  <button ng-class="{active: active1}" ng-mousedown="active1 = !active1">
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="active1" ng-change="active1=!active1"/>
```

Comment: Isn't `ng-change` (or rather `onchange`) fired after `ng-click` (`onclick`)?

Comment: +1 It works (still not quite clear why)! ... Thanks!